# Can I modify a "referenced" integer variable?

Tags: java

I realize that if I pass an object as a parameter of a function and do changes to it, the changes "stay" with the object. But it is not the case for an integer.

```
public void start() {
    int x = 100;
    modify(x);
    // I would like x to be 200 now. But it isn't :(
}

public void modify(int y) {
    y *= 2;
}
```

So basically, is there a way to achieve what I wanted in the code above? Is it possible to modify an integer like that (like an object reference)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While working with `primitives` there is no concept of "`reference`". But you may achieve what you want by doing something like below:

`x = modify(x);` may be code want.

Now `x` contains the results of `modify(x)` method invocation.

Comment: Not the code I need - but definitely the answer I required :)

Comment: All primitives have object wrappings. So why not use Integer??
Integer x = new Integer(5);
modify(x);

Comment: @AlexCalugarescu: all wrapper classes are immutable. Even though it is allowed to do what you suggested, it is no more than extra overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. Primitives are passed by value. (References are also passed by value. You can't modify an object reference; you can only modify the object that is referenced.) The best you can do is:

```
public void start() {
    int [] x = {100};
    modify(x);
    // x[0] is now 200 :)
}

public void modify(int []y) {
    y[0] *= 2;
}
```

The array reference `x` is passed by value, but you can modify the array elements. Note that passing an `Integer` won't help, because `Integer` objects are immutable.

Alternatively, you can redesign your method to return the doubled value and assign it in the calling code (as [Nambari suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558606/535871)).

Answer (score 2):

A third possibility, beside [passing an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558612/1347968) or [using a return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558606/1347968), would be to pass an object of some `ValueHolder` class with a getter and setter:

```
public class IntValueHolder
{
    private int value;
    public int getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }
    public void setValue(final int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This is technically very similar to passing an array, but is IMHO a bit cleaner, i.e. it better describes your intent.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is get the return value of the modify() method and assign it to the variable as follows.

```
public void start() {
    int x = 100;
    x=modify(x);   
}

public int modify(int y) {
    return y *= 2;
}
```

Comment: No need to use compound assignment in `modify`; just `return y * 2;`. Also, isn't this just Nambari's answer?